# Planet CLI - problem with authorization in planet init

Tags: planet

I try to use Planet CLI or pclip plugin for download a Planet data. But I've got a problem with authorization in the client.

When I try a command `planet init` or `pclip planetkey` in the command line and enter email and password.

I get an error:

> Unexpected response: invalid parameters, login process has changed

How do I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue with the client and is being fixed. You can follow [this ticket](https://github.com/planetlabs/planet-client-python/issues/148) to track progress.

In the meantime, you can use the `-k` parameter to provide authentication when using the Planet client.

For example:

`planet -k API_KEY_HERE data search ...`

Update: This has been [fixed](https://github.com/planetlabs/planet-client-python/pull/152). Look for a new release on PyPI.